# compare where in

Tags: java, refactoring, code-duplication

I'm looking for some library with static functions to eliminate duplication in code that compare "things".

```
(evil.equals(s1) || evil.equals(s2) || evil.equals(s3))
(evil == enum1 || evil == enum2 || evil == enum3)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like

```
Arrays.asList(s1, s2, s3).contains(evil)
```

That would be a little shorter

Comment: Shorter but expensive. What your code does is creating an array and iterating through it.

Answer (score 2):

How about this for starters:

```
boolean equalsAny(Object object, Object... others) {
    for (Object other : others) {
        if (other.equals(object))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

Object evil = ...;
SpecialClass special = ...;
AnotherClass another = ...;
if (equalsAny(evil, "aString", special, Integer.valueOf(42), another)) {
    // match found!
}
```

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Huh? What do you mean?

Comment: `Object...` is an array. If you were to keep it you would have a new object. However, with Escape Analysis, the JVM can determine that this object is only used in this method and allocate it on the stack (or remove it completely)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Ohh I see what you're saying - Escape Analysis is what the JVM is using to optimize this method. Never heard of that before; very cool! Thanks!

Comment: Search for `-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis` which is on by default from Java 6 update 19.

Comment: Shakedown, I have the basic idea how to write such functions (but I'm lazy)... What I was looking is some "standard" library that have overloaded methods and can compare enums too. And of course objects of the same type.

Comment: @adfgvx: I'm not aware of any such library, but keep in mind that `equals` is defined on all objects so you don't need to have overloaded methods - they can just use `Object` and leave it up to the specific classes to define `equals` in a meaningful way. This will work with `enum`s too.

Comment: @Shakedown: what i thought with overloading is to write more functions to avoid array creation...

`void func(Object o) {}
 void func(Object o1, Object o2) {}
 void func(Object o1, Object o2, Object o3) {}
 void func(Object o1, Object o2, Object o3, Object... args) {}`

Comment: @adfgvx: Don't worry about array creation, the compiler will optimize it :) See Peter Lawrey's comments above regarding Escape Analysis

Comment: @Shakedown, The JIT compiler optimises it, rather than the javac compiler. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For the second line, a switch statement would do nicely:

```
switch (evil) {
   case enum1:
   case enum2:
   case enum3:
      //code
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a special library, but if you don't care about performance, the following should work out of the box:

```
Arrays.asList(s1, s2, s3).contains(evil);
```

A simple implementation without the overhead of list creation could be something like:

```
public static boolean equalsAny(Object obj, Object ... others) {
    for (Object other: others) {
        if (obj.equals(other))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```